# Sharepoint 2013 - Group by Column - DVWP

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, group-by, sharepoint-2013

What is the best method to group by column like the example below.

[Group By Column - Sample Image](http://themediumgiant.com/tmp/SP/GroupByColumn.PNG)

I am using a DVWP with an xslt link to style the output. I managed to group the results together via the list view settings of SP, but I want to also group and display the Group Title.

```
<div class="bigBox">
  <div class="smallBox">
    <h2>Group Title 1</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Title 1 - Message</li>
      <li>Title 2 - Message</li>
      <li>Title 4 - Message</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="smallBox">
    <h2>Group Title 2</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Title 3 - Message</li>
      <li>Title 5 - Message</li>
      <li>Title 6 - Message</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The xsl link I use, is the standard DVWP code generated by SPD.

I hope I explained the issue well. Please let me know if there's anything you want me to explain further.

Thank you in advance.
George

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the XSLT mentioned into the question.